# Shell script: multiple or operator condition with not equal in if

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

cat test.sh

```
read value
if [ $value != "y" ] || [ $value != "n" ]
then
echo "invalid"
exit 1
fi
```

I tried passing value at runtime, like "n", "m" and "y". And I am expecting script to exit when I pass "m". But its not working as expected.

NOTE: The above code works with Bash shell.

I tried several syntax but no luck.

```
if [ $value != "y" || $value != "n" ]

if [[ $value != "y" ] || [ $value != "n" ]]

if [[ $value != "y" ]] || [[ $value != "n" ]]

if [[ $value != "y" || $value != "n" ]]
```

sometimes condition does not satisfy

Please help in fixing this issue

Comment: With what shell are you running this code?

Comment: What is the value of `$value` when you test your code? Do you get the same error message every time? What shell are you using? Is the script file a Unix text file or a Windows text file (with CRLF line endings)?

Comment: its executing in bash shell, when the value is been passed other than y or n then it should exit the script

Comment: Your logic is wrong and you need to quote the variable expansion, but it's unclear what is your actual issue with this question. Is your issue that you're always getting an error message (which would indicate that something is wrong with the formatting of the text), or is the issue that you sometimes get an error and sometimes not? It's further confusing that you say that it _works_ in `bash`. This leaves us wondering in what shell it does not work. In short, you will need to closer specify what you're doing and under what circumstances the script fails, and _how_ it fails.

Comment: the condition is not working as expected. Basically I want to get the value at runtime and  check whether its "y" (or) "n", if anything other than that should exit . How to configure this

Comment: Where does the `fail` come from in your output? It's not there in the code shown. What does it mean that you had "no luck" with the lower set of conditionals? What did you expect to happen, and what exactly happened? Please show how the full script you have, and how you run it. You're asking for help from people who have never seen your code before, and who don't know what you are actually trying to do, so don't require them to guess -- it doesn't help in getting your problem solved.

Comment: @ilkkachu I have re-edit my question, can you please check now

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still not clear what you mean by "sometimes condition does not satisfy". When does it, and when does it not (although you expect it to do)?

Answer (score 3):

> And I am expecting script to exit when I pass "m". But its not working as expected.

Ok, so, you have the conditional:

```
if [ $value != "y" ] || [ $value != "n" ]; then
    echo "invalid"
    ...
```

If `$value` is `m`, it's not equal to `y`, and it's not equal to `n`, so that evaluates to (true *or* true), which is true, and the commands inside the `if` are executed.

If `$value` if `y`, it *is* equal to `y`, but is not equal to `n`, so that evaluates to (false *or* true), which **is true**, so the commands inside the `if` are executed again.

The only case where the commands inside the `if` would not be executed would be the case where  both tests would be false -- `$value` would need to be equal to `y` and equal to `n` at the same time.

Basically, what you want here is this

```
if [ $value = "y" ] || [ $value = "n" ]; then
    echo ok
else
    echo invalid
fi
```

But without the useless "ok" branch, so the condition inverted:

```
if ! ( [ $value = "y" ] || [ $value = "n" ] ); then
    echo invalid
fi
```

Now, the inverse of (A *or* B) is not (*not* A *or not* B), but (*not* A ***and*** *not* B), so that's what your condition needs to say.

Also, you want to quote the variable expansion, because otherwise whitespace in the contents of `$value` will mess up how the command is interpreted, so:

```
if [ "$value" != "y" ] && [ "$value" != "n" ]; then
    echo invalid
fi
```

(or use `[[ $value != "y" ]]` etc., since `[[` is special and one of the few cases where whitespace doesn't cause splitting.)

See also:

- [Using the not equal operator for string comparison](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/67898/170373)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373)